# Room availability check SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have one booking table which has 2 columns DateFrom and DateTo.
Now when an user want to check availability of room , I should verify with this booking table and need to confirm whether the room is available or not.

I am passing 2 parameters @datefrom and @dateto to my sql query.

```
declare @DateFrom datetime
declare @DateTo datetime

set @DateFrom ='10/15/2015'
set @DateTo = '10/18/2015'

SELECT * FROM tblBooking WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE  
((DateFrom <= @DateFrom AND DateTo >= @DateFrom)
OR (DateTo >= @DateTo AND  DateFrom <= @DateTo))
```

Problem is if another user had booked for 10/16/2015 to 10/17/2015, then system should should show "not available" message.

Pls leave why it is "select *" , what type of rooms... pls help on where condition to check availability.

Comment: Post your query and of course, tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You might also take a look this before you continue littering your database with the NOLOCK hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Then why are you doing SELECT * instead of a query that will output 'Not Available'?   Are you handling some of the logic in a front end app, and if so, then what?

Comment: Can you only book one resource per day?  The details make it look like you only have one room.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: If all you care about is the WHERE condition then @jamesz already gave you the answer.   There is nothing in any of your updates that shows why his answer wouldn't work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Just check with something like this?

```
select * from table 
where DateTo > @datefrom and DateFrom < @dateto
```

Comment: @Nic If this isn't what you're looking for, please tell what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are really trying to do is check against is a single resource then you have a pretty finite list of scenarios to check up against.
[image]

Your data provided doesn't take into consideration things like checkout time and a room being available at perhaps 4PM one day, but not 6 hours earlier on the same day.  Since you didn't specify any of that criteria, I won't carve out those details specifically.  I believe you can solve all of these with 3 "Where" conditions;

```
WHERE
(
@DateFrom BETWEEN DateFrom and DateTo /* Solves 1,4,5 */
OR
@DateEnd BETWEEN DateFrom and DateTo /* Solves 2,4,5 */
OR
DateFrom BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateEnd /* Solves 2,3,5 */
)
```

Conditions 1,3 are solved for once, conditions 2,4,5 are solved for many times, but they only have to be solved for once.  In theory if your tblBookings had a room number in it, this would return the list of all available resources within that time span.

Comment: All of these are also solved by the one condition in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when count(*) = 0 then 'Available' else 'Not available' end
from tblBooking
where DateFrom <= @DateTo and DateTo >= @DateFrom
```

The only thing I can figure is that you want to check for overlapping date ranges and that you need (despite the `select *`) to return a yes/no indicator on availability. If a row exists then `count(*)` will be greater than zero and thus there would be a conflict.

Comment: Well, this is exactly the same as my answer, except with including the the start and end dates, which might or might not be the correct way, since for example hotel rooms are available if the previous reservation ends the same day when the new one starts

Comment: @JamesZ I hear your frustration with the question. I thought perhaps the aggregation test was maybe what OP needed. It's a good point about the ends of the range. Considering OP's own answer yours should have been accepted.

Comment: Well he is saying something strange about `Pls leave why it is "select *"` which I would assume nobody understands :D

Comment: I read that as "Please leave (out/alone) issues/comments/questions about why I'm using `select *`.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case you cite
(DateFrom is 10/16/2015, DateTo is 10/17/2015,
@DateFrom is 10/15/2015, @DateTo is 10/18/2015)
, the logic would be:

```
(DateFrom >= @DateFrom AND DateTo >= @DateFrom
 AND DateTo <= @DateTo AND  DateFrom <= @DateTo)
```

As the entries in the table have to be between the end points.

Comment: I will check all other cases. Pls help on my current case explained in my question.

Comment: This doesn't work at all, if there is existing reservation that starts before the checked period, this doesn't find it because DateFrom >= @DateFrom is not true

Comment: @JamesZ, does this work for the specific case noted? That is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding this in my existing query:

```
OR ( @DateFrom <= DateFrom AND DateTo <= @DateTo)
```

Comment: That likely doesn't cover all your overlap scenarios.